# Plone flowplayer won't autostart video

Tags: video, plone, flowplayer

I'm not sure why flowplayer won't automatically start the video, you have to press play in order to start. The autoplay doesn't seem to have an effect.

```
<tal:js metal:fill-slot="javascript_head_slot">   

<script type="text/javascript">
flowplayer("player1", "flowplayer.swf",
{ clip: { autoPlay: true, autoBuffering: true } }
 ); 
</script>

</tal:js>
```

If any other coded is needed, let me know.

Comment: Do you need to wrap it a function that's called when the document is loaded? jq(document).ready(function(){ // code here... })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason that portion of js code wasn't executing or being overwritten by Plone so I got rid of all that js code on top.

There is an `init.js` script that plone's flowplayer uses. In there you can see that it looks for an `a` tag inside a `div` tag so I changed my html code to reflect that. In addition, I gave my div another class (autoPlayVideo) so that the code I added in `init.js` can recognize the flowplayer inside the `div` and let it auto play (auto play the video if it's in a div and does not have a splash image). Anything else that uses `init.js` won't be affected.

html before:

```
    <a class="autoFlowPlayer" href="video.flv" id="player1">
```

html after (There is no "player1" id needed anymore):

```
    <div class="autoFlowPlayer autoPlayVideo">
        <a href="video.flv"></a>
    </div>
```

init.js:

```
    if ($self.is('div')) {
    ...
        if ($self.is('.autoPlayVideo')) {
            config.clip.autoPlay = true;
        }
    }
```

If anyone else has an even better solution, please share :-)

Comment: I just think I found something in the ZMI, portal_properties then flowplayer_properties, I think this is the global config for flowplayer. I'm going to try this at work tomorrow, there is a clip/autoPlay checkbox. This might be a cleaner solution than what I did.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work for my case at least. No matter what this autoPlay value is, because I don't have a splash image, init.js will reset autoplay =false.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your player1 element contains HTML element or text inside, for example:

```
<a id="player1" href="video.mp4">Hello world</a>
```

If you want autoplay, it has to be empty:

```
<a id="player1" href="video.mp4"></a>
```

Comment: I have no text inside. This is my html code:
`<a id="player1" class="autoFlowPlayer" href="video.flv">
</a>`